# How do you differentiate this differential equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, differentiation, calculus

I have to differentiate this equation (Gravitational force between N-Bodies)

$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vec{r_i}(t)=G
  \sum_{k=1}^{n} 
  \frac
    {m_k(\vec{r}_k(t)-\vec{r}_i(t))}
    {\lvert\vec{r}_k(t)-\vec{r}_k(t)\rvert^3}
\end{align}$

where $\vec{r_{i/k}}(t)$ is the position of a body in 3D space and $m_{i/k}$ is its mass

How would you calculate $\frac{d^3}{dt^3}\vec{r_i}(t), \frac{d^4}{dt^4}\vec{r_i}(t) ...$?

Edit: I know that solving for $\vec{r_i}(t)$ is very complicated but is that also the case for the third derivative of $\vec{r_i}(t)$? I'm asking because since $\vec{r_i}(0)$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r_i}(0)$ are given (and therefore $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\vec{r_i}(0)$ is also known) one could make a Taylor series with $\frac{d^3}{dt^3}\vec{r_i}(t), \frac{d^4}{dt^4}\vec{r_i}(t)$ and so on

Answer (score 2):

The right hand side of your equation is an explicit function of $r_{i}$ and the $r_{k}$s.  One just needs to apply the chain and product rules from introductory calculus.  The expression will be super-ugly, and will have explicit $\dot r$'s in it, but I don't see what difficulty you're having with the computation.

Perhaps the only complication is that your denominator is really:

$$\left[\left({\vec r}_{i} - {\vec r}_{k}\right)\cdot\left({\vec r}_{i} - {\vec r}_{k}\right)\right]^{3/2}$$

Comment: I am in 12th grade and we never covered differential equations or in general differentiating these types of equations but I am trying to understand it because im doind a presentation on the n body problem so i want to understand what im trying to explain. I have searched on the internet about this but i never really found a comprehensible answer

Comment: @SIMONEESPOSITO: I mean, this isn't fundamentally different than saying:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(f(t))\right)^{2} = 2 f(t){\dot f(t)}$$, just that the right hand function is more complicated.  There is no solving differential equations here.

Comment: you just need to keep on taking time derivatives of both sides, and applying the chain and product rules.

Comment: *im doind a presentation on the n body problem* OK, but why would you want to talk about third, fourth, and higher derivatives? They are irrelevant even in the two-body problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even for three bodies it's really complicated

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem

Unless someone else knows different, it would seem like a job for computer simulation.

Comment: I know that solving for r(t) is very complicated but is that also the case for the third derivative of r(t)? I'm asking because since r(0), r'(0) are given (and therefore r''(0) is also known) one could make a taylor series with r'''(0), r'''(0) and so on

Comment: @SIMONEESPOSITO What you said in your comment should be in the body of the question and I would strongly suggest you make clear what you are trying to do with an edit.  As it stands it reads like a "do my homework for me by differentiating this" question.